# No actualiza version de php CLI en ubuntu 17.04

Tags: php, apache, apache2

estoy tratando de actulizar mi version de php, de la 7.1.9 a la 7.2.7

Utilizo:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get install php7.2 php7.2-common
sudo apt-get install php7.2 php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-json php7.2-opcache php7.2-mysql php7.2-mbstring
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

luego corro php -v

y me tira:

PHP 7.1.9 (cli) (built: Sep 18 2017 02:29:39) ( NTS )

no logro que me tome la version que acabo de bajar.

Intento con:
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2

y tampoco, nuevamente:

PHP 7.1.9 (cli) (built: Sep 18 2017 02:29:39) ( NTS )

pruebo con:
sudo a2enmod php7.2 (antes verifico que apache esta detenido)

que me regresa:

Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php7.2:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
Module mpm_prefork already enabled
Considering conflict php5 for php7.2:
Module php7.2 already enabled

y hasta aqui llegue, porque sigue con:

PHP 7.1.9 (cli) (built: Sep 18 2017 02:29:39) ( NTS )

Agradeceré enormemente ayuda, ya no se que comando ejecutar.

Answer (score 0):

hola antes de instalar cualquier version php o de otro lenguage primero deberias ver si ya la tienes instalada, quiza no te lo permita  instalar de nuevo el sistema,etc para eso ejecuta este comando desde la terminal de ubuntu:

```
php -v
```

despues miras los modulos instalados en ubuntu con el siguiente comando:

```
$ dpkg — get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep php7.0
```

despues sencillamente lo instalas con el siguiente comando :

```
sudo apt install php7.2 php7.2-common php7.2-cli php7.2-fpm
```

pero antes de nada que no se te olvide agregar el :

> 1. Add PPA ondrej/php

con el siguiente comando:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
```

[mas info aqui](https://ayesh.me/Ubuntu-PHP-7.2)

Comment: No, no funciona. Si te fijas los comados que me has indicado, son los mismos que están en mi pregunta.

Comment: intenta de la siguiente manera : apt-get install php7.2 y despues  apt-get install php-pear php7.2-curl php7.2-dev php7.2-mbstring php7.2-zip php7.2-mysql php7.2-xml   mas info aqui: https://fearby.com/article/how-to-install-php-7-2-latest-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: bueno, me voy aproximando pero aun no sale, si corro el siguiente comando:

sudo apt-get install php7.2-cli

me responde:

php7.2-cli ya está en su versión más reciente (7.2.7-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).

tiro php -v

y otra vez:

PHP 7.1.9 (cli) (built: Sep 18 2017 02:29:39) ( NTS )

Es decir, la evrsion que necesito esta instalada, pero php no la esta tomando.

¿Como seria la forma de indicarle a php que deje de usar la actual 7.1 y tome la nueva 7.2 ya instalada?

Comment: le corro sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2 y tampoco, sigue tomando la version 7.1